# Is relative path possible in eclipse.ini file to make -vm to look a directory under eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to make -vm parameter to look at relative jre path ?

We have a jre under eclipse directory and we want to make -vm to point to this relative path instead of full path ? Something like ./jre7/bin/javaw.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rename the folder `jre7` to `jre` and if you don't use `-vm` in `eclipse.ini`, **Eclipse uses the JRE/JDK in the subfolder `jre`**.

Relative paths in `eclipse.ini` are resolved relative to the working directory, not relative to the location of `eclipse.ini`. For example, if your working directory is `/path/to/working-dir`, `-vm jre7/bin/javaw.exe` is equivalent to `-vm /path/to/working-dir/jre7/bin/javaw.exe`.